# Does the value of valence band edge's energy(Ev) and Conduction band edge's energy(Ec) change with temperature?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I am trying to understand band gap and fermi level concepts. In regards to the same, to explain a particular phenomenon, I need to know the dependence of Ev and Ec on temperature. According me to it should be dependent on temperature. If it is so, can someone provide me the mathematical model for it?

Comment: The gap does change with temperature. Expressions can be found in most semiconductor physics books such as Sze.